# I somehow made edit/object mode monochrome. How do I revert to default render settings?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

Relatively new to Blender here.  While doing a bunch of Control-Z undos in edit mode, I somehow made both edit and object mode monochrome when I fat-fingered something.  I've been searching through all the render settings but can't figure out how I got it to this state.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QKOI.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is what you mean but you are in Texture display mode...see that little red and white checked ball to the right of the "Object Mode" dropdown?  Just hit 'Z' once to go to wireframe, or twice to go to Solid display mode...or click on that ball to choose a different rendering mode.  You probably hit Alt-Z instead of Ctrl-Z.